# How to access Activity's view from other Activity class

Tags: android

My problem is when I change the text of a `TextView` in my Main class, it returns nullPointerException.

here's my code:

main.xml

```
<TabHost ...>
  <RelativeLayout ...>
    <LinearLayout ...>
      <TabWidget .../>
       <FrameLayout ...>
        <ListView ../>
       </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout ...>
      <TextView android:id="@+id/status" ... />

    </LinearLayout>

  </RelativeLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Main class

```
....
TabHost tabHost;
TabHost.TabSpec spec;
Intent intent;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

    //display implementation of TabHost
    ....
    //Contacts tab
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Contacts.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("contacts").setIndicator("Contacts",   res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_contacts)).setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

}
```

Then class that will update the ***status TextView*** is this:

Contacts class

```
public class Contacts extends ListActivity{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       //gather info to display in ListView
       ....

       updateStatus("New Status");
    }

    private void updateStatus(String status){
       TextView labelView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status);
       labelView.setText(status);
    }

}


labelView.setText(status); Error occurs here....
```

Pls help me. I cant find any solution in the net.
I need to update the status....

heres my manifest:

```
...
 <application ...>
   <activity android:name=".Main" ... >
     <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
   </activity>

   <activity android:name=".Contacts"  android:label="@string/app_name"></activity> 
    <activity android:name=".OtherClass"  android:label="@string/app_name"></activity> 
    <activity android:name=".OtherClass2"  android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
 </application>
...
```

In advance, thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You see the view with id `status` exists in the Main activity context, while you are trying to find it from the Contacts activity context. Thats why it is returning `null`.

Try this, it should solve your problem :

**Main Activity**

```
public class Main extends Activity {

    public static String sStatus = "";

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

            //display implementation of TabHost
            ....

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        TextView labelView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status);
        labelView.setText(status);
    }
}
```

**Contacts Activity**

```
public class Contacts extends ListActivity{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       //gather info to display in ListView
       ....

       updateStatus("New Status");
    }

    private void updateStatus(String status){
        Main.sStatus = status;
    }

}
```

Comment: Sir Aki, pls give me implementation of sStatus in Main class... because I also tried this solution... but gives me an error..

Comment: i declared public TextView sStatus; but Cant find the Main.sStatus.

Comment: Please go through my code again. `sStatus` is not a TextView, it is a String variable, and it is static.

Comment: My implementation is a bit buggy, but you can sure figure something out with a little tweaking :)

Comment: Please do accept the answer (click on the tick beside my answer) if it solved your problem.

Comment: This wasn't the exact solution I  used but it pointed me in the right direction so plus 1.  I had an activity that could be launched from one of many activities so I opted to use shared preferences to store a flag and then checked the status of that flag in onResume to determine if a method needed to be executed.

Answer (score 0):

View is only associated with Main.
You have to reset the contentView in Contacts.
Modified code

```
public class Contacts extends ListActivity{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);

       //gather info to display in ListView
       ....

       updateStatus("New Status");
    }

    private void updateStatus(String status){
       TextView labelView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status);
       labelView.setText(status);
    }

}
```

Comment: guys! i tried this before, then i tried it again. Still an error, because Contacts.class is the view for a TAB of a TabHost.