# Change tab names in app

Tags: android, singleton

I have in my settings page a toggle. The toggle switches languages from English to french. It works at changing all the labels to french but the tab bars are staying the same.

I created a singleton class and called it like so:

```
Singleton.getInstance().changeTabLang();
```

This is getting an instance of my MainActivity and calling this function:

```
public void changeTabLang(){
    tabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    for (int i = 0; i < tabHost.getTabWidget().getTabCount(); i++) {
        ((TextView) tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i)).setText(R.string.loginTab);
    }
}
```

Here is my Singleton:

```
public class Singleton {
private static MainActivity instance = null;

private Singleton() {       }

public static MainActivity getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
              if (instance == null) {
                    instance = new MainActivity ();
              }
        }
        return instance;
}

}
```

The issue is that my `tabHost` cannot be found because the view for my MainActivity isn't available.

How can I get my MainActivity's view in order to get my tabHost?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The issue is that my tabHost cannot be found because the view for my
>   MainActivity isn't available.

Your singleton implementation is incorrect for two reasons. First, you **never** instantiate an `Activity` by yourself, that's something the Android system should do. If you instantiate the `Activity` by yourself it never enters the lifecycle callbacks so there's no view for it. Secondly, you should never use a static `Activity` reference because you risk leaking it.

> How can I get my MainActivity's view in order to get my tabHost?

You shouldn't try to access the view or content of an `Activity` from outside of it(because of the way the Android system works, that activity could as well be dead when you try accessing it). Instead you should just set somewhere some flag or something else that an update it's required(and setup the `Activity` to do any update). For example you could create a custom `Application` class for your app and set there the language change update:

```
/**
 * register the custom application class in your manifest under the
 * application tag with android:name="your.package.CustomApplication"
**/
public class CustomApplication extends Application {

    public static final int ENGLISH_LANGUAGE = 0x3333;
    public static final int FRENCH_LANGUAGE = 0x4444;

    private int currentLanguage = ENGLISH_LANGUAGE;

    public int getCurrentLanguage() {
        return currentLanguage;
    }

    public void setCurrentLanguage(int currentLanguage) {
        this.currentLanguage = currentLanguage;
    }

}
```

Then when your user sets the new language you'll do:

```
((CustomApplication)getApplicationContext()).setCurrentLanguage(CustomApplication.FRENCH_LANGUAGE);
```

Then any other `Activity` could see the current set language through:

```
((CustomApplication)getApplicationContext()).getCurrentLanguage();
```

and change stuff around(this would be done in the `onResume()` method that will be called just before the `Activity` becomes visible to the user).

Comment: I only call my MainActivity once to set up all the tabs and some other things. How can I change the tabHost in the onResume without trying to access it outside the activity? Should I just start the MainActivity over again?

Comment: @BigT In `MainActivity` in the `onCreate()` method get the current language from the `Application` class. In the `onResume()` method of the `MainActivity` check again the current set language from the Application class and see if it's different than the language you first saw in the `onCreate()` method. If it is then there was a language change and update what you want with the new values. When the user changes the language in the preferences use the `setCurrentLanguage()`. When the user will get back the onResume method will see the difference and update itself.

Comment: Well if I just have `MainActivity` as the set up for my `tabHost` it wont get called again. After it sets up the tabs it goes to the first one and that calls it own activity. The `onResume()` method won't be called.

Comment: @BigT It's not clear what you're doing. *if I just have MainActivity as the set up for my tabHost it wont get called again.* - Aren't the settings page where you change the language in another activity? Are you using tabs with activities(the onResume method should be called no matter what though)?

Comment: I am working with a demo app and trying to add a few things. The MainActivity is a FragmentActivity and it creates the FragmentTabBar at the bottom of the page. The tabs are handled by the fragment classes like settings. So in the settings page I need to change the language in the app. Make more sense?

Answer (score 0):

I am have not tried this for a singleton or tabhost, but how about adapting this, which works for a textview in my app?

[how access activity view from other activity class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7803411/how-access-activity-view-from-other-activity-class)

To summarise, I did this:

In MainActivity:

```
public static string fred="";


... onResume() {
    TextView frederick = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status_text); //status_text is a textview in my xml
    frederick.setText(fred);
}
```

In other activity:

```
MainActivity.fred="updating fred";
```

It worked perfectly for my app, as I say I don't know whether your particular scenario renders this unworkable.